# How can I use array_push to add a key value pair in a foreach loop through database query results in PHP/Laravel to flag each row returned?

Tags: php, laravel, array-push

I have a function which retrieves all comments for a post when a show posts button is clicked. The comments are then displayed using Javascript and what I am looking to do is to add a key value pair to the array which will tell my javascript if the comment owner is the logged in user or not, thus allowing me to then add edit and delete buttons to that user's posts only.

This may or may not be the best way to make this comparison but it's a way I cooked up in my infinite inexperience so I can use javascript to show the comments and allow editing/deletion of the comment. I know I could add a column my_posts to the DB table and keep this empty, then use array_push to add the appropriate value to this field but is the way I've tried here possible?

my function is here:

```
public function postGetComments(Request $request) {
     $post = $request['postid'];
     $comments = DB::table('comments')
             ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
             ->select('comments.*', 'users.username')
             ->where('post_id', '=', $post)
             ->orderby('created_at', 'desc')
             ->get()
             ;
     foreach ($comments->get() as $comment) {
                $user = Auth::user();
                if ($user->id == $comment->user_id) {
                    $comment['my_post'] = 'true';
                } else {
                    $comment['my_post'] = 'false';
                }
     }
     return response()->json(['commentsForPost' => $comments]); 
}
```

I am getting an error as there is a problem with my foreach loop at the end. Without this loop the query retrieves and displays all comments as designed. I'm very new to Laravel (using 5.2) and I'm wondering what I've done wrong while trying to push the key my_post, compare the comments.user_id to the user.id and add the value true/false as appropriate to the array? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have already run the get() method on your $comments query. Change your foreach loop to this

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
                $user = Auth::user();
                if ($user->id == $comment->user_id) {
                    $comment['my_post'] = 'true';
                } else {
                    $comment['my_post'] = 'false';
                }
     }
```

Comment: I tried this first and it still throws an error. Thanks but it doesn't work.

Comment: From the server log the error is:

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

I guess this means I'm not getting an array from my query and need to first convert the results to an array, right?

Comment: @David `$comments` is an array of stdClass objects. When you loop through the array, each `$comment` is a stdClass object. You should access the data like `$comment->my_post`, not `$comment['my_post']`.

Comment: @patricus  `$comment['my_post'] = 'true'` is the way I thought I was to use instead of `array_push()` to add a key/value pair to an existing array. my_post does not exist in the table; it is a new key/value pair I am trying to add to each comment to flag if the post belongs to the logged in user who queries the database so I can then add "edit" and "delete" buttons to the comment if it is their post, by setting the value to the key as true or false. I tried using `json_decode($comments, true)` but this still did not work, although there is no error in the server log if I run that code.

Comment: @David `$comment` is not an array. It is an object. Square brackets (`[]`) are for array access. Arrows (`->`) are for object access. If you attempt to access `$comment['my_post']`, you will get an error because the `stdClass` object does not allow array access. If you want to set the `my_post` property, you need to use object access (`$comment->my_post = 'true';`).

Comment: @patricus Thanks, that did actually work. First time I tried it I forgot to remove the quotes from around my_post...thanks again!